# How to set CPU affinity for process with specific name to very high every time that process starts?

Tags: cpu, process

How do I set CPU affinity for process with specific name to very high every time that process starts?

Comment: Are you asking how to set the `nice` value? Or something else?

Comment: schedtool -a 0x1 \`pidof cpu_hog\` after it's running.  Maybe in a startup script?

Comment: new processes with the same name will keep starting and then close itself after a while so I cant use PID. Can I peg this schedtool to a process's name?